# Rails - ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, activerecord, devise, omniauth

I am using facebook authentication for logging in to my app. I did exactly as in this link http://willschenk.com/setting-up-devise-with-twitter-and-facebook-and-other-omniauth-schemes-without-email-addresses/#conclusion

First signup is always successful. But when trying to signup with a second account. I am getting the following error.

[image]

I think (not sure) i have to use `allow_blank: true`. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps both times the email address is `""`. That would cause a conflict since there appears to be a uniqueness constraint on that column.

Comment: Yes exactly. But i don't email column to be unique as my app is totally dependant on omniauth-facebook. But AFAIK devise checks for uniquess of `email column` which i don't want. So how to allow this? I even removed `:validatable` from devise. Still not working. @AdamT

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16689492/554327

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to use Devise's password authentication you could simply create a migration to remove the index:

```
rails g migration RemoveEmailIndexFromUsers
```

And then in the migration:

```
def change
  remove_index :users, :email
end
```

And get rid of the `:database_authenticatable` module from your User model (remove it from the `devise` call).

But IMHO I would not use Devise for a pure OAuth app. The main draw of Devise is that it is a ready made auth solution for password auth. It tries to fill a lot of shoes and is quite complicated as a result.

Sure you can use it with OmniAuth but overriding Devise's controllers, views and params sanitation is almost as much work as rolling your own with Warden.

Comment: Thanj @max. Seems like your migration is clean and straight. But i already used migration in this link. Wondering whats the difference between yours and this. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118039/rails-4-devise-omniauth-email-exists-in-database-error)

Comment: The migration in that answer also removes the NOT NULL constraint on the email column. It also explicitly sets the up / down - I believe rails can automatically figure out that the reverse of removing an index so thats kind of superflous.